# How to show a dialog pane with a progress bar in Python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, rhythmbox

I'm working on Rhythmbox plugin and I need to show a dialog pane with a progress bar.
Here's my code :

```
def download_all_lyrics_action_callback(self, action):
        progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar();

        dialog = Gtk.Dialog(_('lLyrics Preferences'), self.shell.get_property('window'),
                Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL | Gtk.DialogFlags.DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, (Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        content_area = dialog.get_content_area()
        content_area.pack_start(progressbar, True, True, 0)

        dialog.show_all()

        dialog.run()

        total = len(self.shell.props.library_source.props.query_model)
        i = 1;
        for row in self.shell.props.library_source.props.query_model:
            entry = row[0]
            title = entry.get_string(RB.RhythmDBPropType.TITLE)
            artist = entry.get_string(RB.RhythmDBPropType.ARTIST)
            print(title + " - " + artist)

            self.get_lyrics_for_song(title, artist)
            progressbar.set_fraction(i/total) 
        dialog.hide()
```

The problem is it stop in `dialog.run()` instruction. I have also tested some code I found but without success. Can you please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dialog.run()` starts a main loop which runs until the user has closed the dialog or pressed one of its response buttons. For what you want, it would be better to call `dialog.show()` instead.

Make sure you run the main loop (`while Gtk.events_pending(): Gtk.main_iteration(False)`) after each call to change the progress bar; or update the progress bar in an idle function. Otherwise you won't see the changes.